# I have a row from a html table in the form : $(row).text(). How do I feed this into a input type="hidden" element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have two html tables: stockdataTable which gets its data from a database call.
result table which is empty initially and dynamically has rows appended to it when a user clicks a row in the stockdataTable.

I capture the selected row using 
row = $(this).clone(); and append it to resultTable.

I have a html form "buyTrade" which has 3 elements, one of type hidden, a text field to enter a value, and a submit button.

how do I copy the row data of result table onto the hidden element in the form?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var row

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs();

    $('#stockdataTable tr').click(function (event) {
        row = $(this).clone();
        $('#resultTable').append(row);
        $("#resultTable").on("append", "tr", function () {
            alert($(this) + " was added");
        }, function () {
            alert($(this) + " was removed");
        });
        $(row).click(function (event) {
            $(this).remove();
            var row = $(this).text();
        });
    });
});

function reg() {
    alert($(row).text());
    $('tradeDetail').val("$(row).text()");
    return true
}

</script>
```

Form code:

```
<form name="buyTrade" method="GET" action="/Stock/BuyServlet" onsubmit="return reg()">
    <input type="hidden" name="tradeDetail" value="" id="tradeDetail"></input>Qty:
    <input type="text" name="qty">
    <input type="submit" value="Buy">
</form>
```

Comment: Not sure what your asking.

Comment: I edited the typo - row.text() converts the cloned row into text form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out:

```
    var row

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs();

        $('#stockdataTable tr').click(function (event) {
            row = $(this).clone();
            $('#resultTable').append(row);
            $("#resultTable").on("append", "tr", function () {
                alert($(this) + " was added");
            }, function () {
                alert($(this) + " was removed");
            });
            $(row).click(function (event) {
                var row = $(this).text().replace(/ /g,''); // replace whitespaces
                $(this).remove();
                reg(row); // call to reg function
            });
        });
    });

    function reg(text) {
        alert(text);
        $('#tradeDetail').val(text);
        return true
    }
```

You need to declare a function with arguments, and then call it when you need. I change `$('#tradeDetail').val(text)` because you miss `#`. Note that `$(this).remove()` is moved after reading his properties, otherwise you can't get the text if it's removed.

Comment: Thanks this worked. However, my URL now looks like this :
http://localhost:8080/Stock/BuyServlet?tradeDetail=%0D%0A++++++%09PIH%0D%0A++++++%091347+Property+Insurance+Holdings%2C+Inc.%0D%0A++++++%097.88%0D%0A++++++%09%2450.1M%0D%0A++++++&qty=14

Comment: I can't access to your localhost xD . If this answer solve your problem, please upvote it and select as correct answer.

Comment: :D I meant how would I format the string input in reg(text) to give a value such as in the URL below:
http://localhost:8080/Stock/BuyServlet?tradeDetail=AAPL+Apple+Computers+1020.32&qty=14

Comment: I said to you that I can't access to your localhost, and nobody can. You need to open your 80 port and redirect your public ip to your private ip, then share your public ip and it works

Comment: I don't think you understand what I am asking.. anyway thanks for your help so far.

Comment: I don't think if you understand that http://localhost only you can access to it. **it is YOUR localhost**

Comment: Oh, I understand now, you need to remove spaces in the url?