# #jquery What is the regex to replace carriage return newline feed and horizontal tab

Tags: jquery, regex

I have generated a get URL using parameters that contains the contents of a table.
However, there are many undesired characters that being sent along that I noticed in the URL.

These I have identified as of being carriage return, new line and horizontal tab.
How do I remove them from the text before I send the data on form submission?

This is the URL that is generated

```
Stock/BuyServlet?tradeDetail=%0D%0A++++++%09TFSCU%0D%0A++++++%091347+Capital+Corp.%0D%0A++++++%0910.27%0D%0A++++++%09%2442.93M%0D%0A++++++&qty=10
```

When what I really want is:

```
Stock/BuyServlet?tradeDetail=TFSCU%2C1347+Capital+Corp.%2C10.27%2C%2442.93M&qty=10
```

The data being passed is :

```
tradeDetail=TFSCU   1347 Capital Corp.  10.27   $42.93M
qty=10
```

---

The data is processed by a Java httpservlet.

Comment: [str_replace()](http://php.net/str_replace)?

Comment: url generated by what? Shouldn't you fix whatever is polluting it?

Comment: I had issues generating the url. I solved it asking this question. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31978905/i-have-a-row-from-a-html-table-in-the-form-row-text-how-do-i-feed-this-i/31981333#31981333

Comment: Are you sure you do not need `Stock/BuyServlet?tradeDetail=TFSCU1347+Capital+Corp.10.27$42.93M&qty=10`? `decodeURIComponent(text1).replace(/[\r\n\t]\+*/g,'').replace(/\+{2,}/g, '+')`?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't manage to remove the special characters before form submission in javascript code.
However, when I received the details in the servlet I performed the following string manipulations to solve my problem.

I've posted the entire code block so that it makes more sense -

```
    Enumeration<String> em = request.getParameterNames();
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();

    if(em == null)
    {
        System.out.println("all is lost");
    }
    while (em.hasMoreElements()) {
        String params = (String) em.nextElement();
        if(params.equalsIgnoreCase(txn_detail) || params.equalsIgnoreCase("qty"))
        {
            String value = request.getParameter(params);

            if(params.equalsIgnoreCase(txn_detail))
            {
                /* This fixed it */
                params = params.replaceAll("[\\r\\n\\t]", " ");
                params = params.replaceAll("  ", " ");
                /* end of fix */
            }
            map.put(params, value);
        }
    }
```